# replace word in text file for phoneme to devnagari

Tags: bash

I am having two text files File_A and File_B. File_A contains following

```
a   अ
aa  आ
b a ब
bh a    भ
c a च
ch a    छ
d a द
dh a    ध
dx a    ड
dxh a   ढ
g a ग
gh a    घ
h a ह
j a ज
jh a    झ
k a क
kh a    ख
l a ल
m a म
n a न
nx a    ण
p a प
ph a    फ
r a र
s a स
sh a    श
t a त
th a    थ
tx a    ट
txh a   ठ
w a व
y a य
z a ज़
b   ब
bh  भ
c   च
ch  छ
d   द
dh  ध
dx  ड
dxh ढ
ee  े
ei  ै
g   ग
gh  घ
h   ह
i   ि
ii  ी
j   ज
jh  झ
k   क
kh  ख
l   ल
m   म
n   न
nx  ण
o    ो
ou   ौ
p   प
ph  फ
r   र
s   स
sh  श
t   त
th  थ
tx  ट
txh ठ
u   ु
uu  ू
w   व
y   य
z   ज़
b aa    बा
bh aa   भा
c aa    चा
ch aa   छा
d aa    दा
dh aa   धा
dx aa   डा
dxh aa  ढा
g aa    गा
gh aa   घा
h aa    हा
j aa    जा
jh aa   झा
k aa    का
kh aa   खा
l aa    ला
m aa    मा
n aa    ना
nx aa   णा
p aa    पा
ph aa   फा
r aa    रा
s aa    सा
sh aa   शा
t aa    ता
th aa   था
tx aa   टा
txh aa  ठा
w aa    वा
y aa    या
z aa    ज़ा
```

If you see in details in above file for example first line "a   अ" there is tab in between roman and devnagari for every line. Indirectly I am trying to replace before tab with after tab. I am trying to replace above phoneme in File_B which contains following.

```
dx o n aa l d s
```

I tried with shell script but getting wrong output. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p q
do
 echo "P is : " $p
 echo "Q is : " $q
 echo "-----------------"
# sleep 3
 sed -i "s/\<$p\>/$q/g" $2
done < $1
```

and getting output is :

```
a   ड ो a   न आ a   ल a द a स
```

I am expecting is :

```
ड ो ना ल द स
```

Python or shell both are accepted.

Comment: Is it safe to assume your files are Unicode, encoded in utf-8?

Comment: @Amol, could you explain it a little more? What do you mean by replacing before tab with after tab? Also, the sample input/output you provide don't seem to be exact. We maybe able to help you better if they are the exact ones shown by your computer.

Comment: I have ways to do this in tcl and perl, btw, but I don't know python well enough.

Comment: @Shawn Yes files are encoded in UTF-8

Comment: @Mihir: If you see in File_A roman character and devnagari character are seperated by tab. I want to replace roman character with devnagari character in File_B. Actually File_A is mapping table. Also the output given by my script is provided in question.

Comment: @Amol, thanks I get it now. I was not reading it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File "awk_script":

```
#! /usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN {
    counter = 0
}

{
    if (FNR == NR) {

        # Store key val pairs from first file

        key[counter] = $1
        value[counter] = $2
        counter++

    } else {

        # Replace stored key val pairs in second file

        for (i = 0 ; i < counter ; i++) {
            gsub(key[i], value[i], $0)
        }

        print
    }
}
```

File "bash_script"

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

file1='File_A'
file2='File_B'
temp_file1="$( mktemp "/tmp/${file1}-XXXXX" )"
awk_script_file_name='awk_script'


#
# Create a temp file which is reverse
# sorted based on length of the keys
# and pass that temp file to awk script
#

awk -F'\t' -v OFS='~' '{

    print $1, $2, length($1)

}' "${file1}" |
    sort -r -n -t '~' -k3 > "${temp_file1}"


awk \
    -F'~' \
    -f "${awk_script_file_name}" \
    "${temp_file1}" \
    "${file2}"

rm "${temp_file1}"
```

---

PS: This script uses BSD variants of the commands and may have to be adjusted to adapt to GNU variants.

Comment: That can give you different results depending on the order of keys that the for loop gives you - for example, for OP's input, I got `दx ो न अअ ल द स` in one test.

Comment: @Shawn, that makes sense. The answer needs correction. Gimme a while.

Comment: @Shawn, I have addressed that issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A perl-based solution:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use open qw/:std :locale/;

my @mappings;
open my $file, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $ARGV[0];
while (my $line = <$file>) {
  chomp $line;
  push @mappings, [ split /\t/, $line ];
}
close $file;

@mappings = sort { my $x = length $b->[0] <=> length $a->[0];
                   $x != 0 ? $x : $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @mappings;
# Precompile the regular expressions
@mappings = map { [ qr/\b$_->[0]\b/, $_->[1] ] } @mappings;

open $file, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $ARGV[1];
while (my $line = <$file>) {
  my $output;
  chomp $line;
  for my $pair (@mappings) {
    my ($roman, $devnagari) = @$pair;
    $line =~ s/$roman/$devnagari/g;
  }
  say $line;
}
```

File_A and File_B are passed on the command line respectively:

```
$ perl convert.pl file_a.txt file_b.txt
ड ो ना ल द स
```

The simple brute global substitution approach doesn't work because, say, `a` is a standalone phoneme and part of many longer ones. If you sort the phoneme list so that the longest tokens are checked first (So that `c a` matches before `c` no matter the order they appear in File_A), it becomes more reasonable to use that approach. You could also try matching the longest possible phoneme from the front of the text, pop it off, and repeat until all the input string is consumed.